# How to record the context of a debugging session?

Tags: debugging

Hunting bugs down is often made of 97% of "*understanding a specific part of the codebase*" and 3% of "*writing a few lines to fix the problem once properly understood*".

When the bug is really difficult to understand, it can means a full day looking at code, trying some experiments, setting breakpoints and stepping through the code to make some sense about this mysterious bug. This full day of work will be remembered in the CVS as a very small change in the codebase (including a brief comment) along with a "*fixed #xxxx issue, [some component] was doing [whatever] wrong...*" as a commit message.

So at the end of the day the bug does not exist anymore, but the only stored information about it will be the diff in the CVS. The hours spent lurking around in a debugger to be able to write the ultimately bug-fixing lines of code will be lost forever.

I want to be able to record some key indicators/events of a debugging session, like:

- functions I set breakpoints in
- input data I manually fed the program with in order to reproduce the problem
- code that were modified and reverted to test some behavior
- callstacks
- ...

Linking this "debug summary" to the commit comment would enable a very faster context switching when later working on a related bug.

Are there some tools that do that?
(This question is language/IDE agnostic...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually keep a written journal during debugging sessions. It's a way of staying productive and keeping the direction. But it's very seldom I actually read the journal afterwards. And I suspect that would be the case with the tool that you're asking for as well.

Instead my advice is to make sure that you only fix the bug once. Add a test case to the automated test suite. Clean up the design around this messy area so that you won't have to spend so much time on it the next time it misbehaves. (The test suite is the best place to keep "the input data I manually fed the program" and what else is "code that was modified and reverted to test some behavior" than an informal unit test?)

Comment: I want to look at some of your debugging journals. How?

Comment: Sorry, but they're not easily shared. I usually use pen and paper (spiral pads) for the journals and my handwriting is truly terrible. But, to give you an idea, they are filled with stuff like: problem to be solved written clearly (very helpful when trying to backtrack!), hypotheses, ideas to try (like checklists), etc. One thing that is usually missing though is the actual solution to the problem; that goes in the check-in comment instead.